ECS Task Fails to Run on t3.small Instance Due to Resource Constraints with SQL Server, API, and Blazor App Containers
Background:
I'm trying to cut the cost of my instance down in half. A t3.medium (2 vCPU, 4 GiB) costs about $.04/hour while a t3.small (2 vCPU, 2 GiB) costs about $.02/hour.
As stated in the title, my Task Definition is made up of an app, database, and api. Theoretically, my memory and compute configurations for each container do "fit" within the t3.small instance (2 vCPU, 2 GiB). While true, after provisioning a t3.small and when creating a service in my cluster, the tasks don't run. However, when I create a new t3.medium instance and retry creating the service, everything runs smoothly.
From what I understand, the t3.small instance isn't quite large enough because there still needs to be some memory for things like the ECS agent (among other things). Therefore, I've gradually been decreasing the amount of CPU and Memory for each container so that I can make room for these things. At the same time, I get the following exception, which tells me that I've decreased the memory capacity too far for one of the containers:

"service was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance ebdf9c31c6b54f20953cbcc0babd1958 has insufficient memory available. For more information, see the Troubleshooting section of the Amazon ECS Developer Guide."

Question(s):
How should I configure my container resources to get to the point where my service runs? Are there any tools that I can use to see how much compute or memory I'm missing/need?
My Task Definition:
{
    "family": "blazor_app_task",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "blazor_app_container",
            "image": "thecodeiackiller/exercise-api-app",
            "cpu": 205,
            "memory": 128,
            "memoryReservation": 102,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "blazor_app_container-8080-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 8080,
                    "hostPort": 8080,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/blazor_app_task",
                    "mode": "non-blocking",
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "max-buffer-size": "25m",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        },
        {
            "name": "sqlserver",
            "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest",
            "cpu": 1024,
            "memory": 922,
            "memoryReservation": 819,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "sqlserver-1433-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 1433,
                    "hostPort": 1433,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
           
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "healthCheck": {
                "command": [
                    "CMD-SHELL",
                    "/opt/mssql-tools18/bin/sqlcmd -C -S localhost -U sa -P 'strongpassword' -Q \"SELECT 1\" || exit 1"
                ],
                "interval": 30,
                "timeout": 5,
                "retries": 3,
                "startPeriod": 45
            },
            "systemControls": []
        },
        {
            "name": "exercise-api",
            "image": "thecodeiackiller/exercise-api-api",
            "cpu": 307,
            "memory": 128,
            "memoryReservation": 102,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "exercise-api-8080-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 5000,
                    "hostPort": 5000,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::448049819404:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::448049819404:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "volumes": [],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "cpu": "2048",
    "memory": "2048",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "enableFaultInjection": false
}


You might be changing the container memory settings, but the total "memory" setting at the task level is still "memory": "2048", in your task definition, which is equal to 100% of the memory on the EC2 instance. Have you tried reducing that value at all?

Mark B - what a pleasure! Per usual, you are correct. I gradually reduced the memory allocation for my task definition until finally settling on 1536 units. Service is up and running. What in your mind and based on what you know about how EC2 instances work, why did you recommend this solution?

The ECS task placement only looks at the task definition memory setting, not the individual container memory settings, to determine if it can place a task on the EC2 instance. Your task was trying to take 100% of the available memory on the instance, which is not allowed, since that would leave no memory available to the operating system.
